# How can i trigger a event when a keyboard shortcut ( Ctrl+F7 ) is fired?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to fetch the event when someone in my Application uses the Shortcut Ctrl+F7. Because I have settings in my application, i dont want anyone to be able to change, but if he has to change those, I can provide him the keyboard shortcut.

How do my Application get to know, when CTRL+F7 is fired ( Application has Focus when the Shortcut is fired.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `OnPreviewKeyDown` method of your main window:

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
    if (e.Key == Key.F7 && (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl)))
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

If your application has several top-level windows, you could create a common base class where you override the method and then inherit all your windows from this one:

```
public abstract class AppWindow : Window
{
    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        if (e.Key == Key.F7 && (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl)))
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : AppWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<local:AppWindow x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow">...</local:AppWindow>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Command binding with Hot Key like this:

```xml
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:CustomCommands.ShortCutCommand}" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_1"  CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{x:Static local:CustomCommands.ShortCutCommand}" Key="F7" Modifiers="Ctrl" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

MainWindow.cs

```cs
public static RoutedCommand ShortCutCommand= new RoutedCommand();
private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
}

private void CommandBinding_Executed_1(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //do something here
}
```